# Unable to locate xpath element text that contains carriage return

Tags: xml, xpath

I am unable to find the text value of the below a tag with the below Xpath. The text that is for the tag contains carriage returns, I assumed that contains would ignore this. Is there a way to search the text attribute and ignore carriage returns?

```
//*[@id='site-wrapper']//a[contains(text(), 'Report')]

<a target="_blank" href="/Bentley/Reports/74/0/5323914">
            <span class="fa fa-print"></span> Report
        </a>
```

Comment: try with `.` (current node) instead of `text()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because [`contains()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-contains) function expects a string argument, thus `text()` node-set will be converted taking the first node in document order and then by [`string()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-string) function.

When you have mixed content, it's always better to use the string value instead of text nodes, like:

```
//*[@id='site-wrapper']//a[contains(., 'Report')]
```

Comment: Good explanation, +1.  Alternatively, to abstract away whitespace without the risk of inadvertent substring matching (`'Bad Report'`, etc): `//*[@id='site-wrapper']//a[normalize-space()='Report']`.

Comment: @Alejandro thank you very much for this solution this has worked for me

Comment: Alejandro, it may happen that there are two consecutive text() node children of an `<a>` such that the 1st ends with "Re" and the 2nd starts with "port". If no single text node child of an `<a>` contains "Report" then the `<a>` elements selected by the expression in this answer are wrong results.

I would use: `//*[@id='site-wrapper']//a[text()[contains(., 'Report')]]`  Please, correct.

Comment: Hi, @DimitreNovatchev! In this case, the OP wants _"to find the text value of the below a tag"_, which I believe it means the string value.

Comment: @Alejandro, Well there might be edge cases like this: `<a target="_blank" href="/Bentley/Reports/74/0/5323914">
 <p>Do Re</p><p>port</p>
</a>`   -- I don't think the OP would want this `<a>` to be selected

Answer (score 1):

Try with normalize-space:

`//*[@id='site-wrapper']//a[normalize-space(text())='Report']`

Comment: I am afraid this method did not work when trying to locate the element

Comment: @Teague, I have updated the answer with the full Xpath, just give a try

Comment: I updated and tried and the code still does not work sorry